# Create Searchable pdf with Tesseract in Android

Tags: java, android, ocr, tesseract

I have been hired by my client to create an android application that would perform Ocr on an image using Tesseract to convert it into a searchable pdf.

Currently am able to extract text from images using this code;

```
  String extractText(String imagePath)
  {
  dataPath= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Android/data/" + appContext.getPackageName() +  "/"; 
    File tessdata = new File(dataPath); 
   if (!tessdata.exists() || !tessdata.isDirectory())
   {
       throw new IllegalArgumentException("Data path must contain subfolder tessdata!");   
} 
     Bitmap image= BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath);
  TessBaseAPI baseApi = new TessBaseAPI();
  baseApi.init(dataPath, "eng"); 

baseApi.setImage(image);
      String recognizedText = baseApi.getUTF8Text();
      baseApi.end();


      return recognizedText;
  }
```

The above code helps me get the text on the image accurately as a string, but I don't know how to create a searchable pdf with this text.

Answer (score 0):

`getUTF8Text` returns only plain text. You'd need to use `TessPDFRenderer` API for PDF output.

https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/tree/master/src/api

Comment: Hi nguyenq, can the  TessPDFRenderer API be used in android studio?.

Comment: Can you provide more info on how to use the API?.

Comment: Check out the unit tests under https://github.com/nguyenq/tess4j/tree/master/src/test . You can apply it to your Android code.

Comment: @nguyenq Can tesseract be used to convert a pdf with images as content to a searchable pdf?

Comment: @nguyenq Can tesseract be used to convert a pdf with images as content to a searchable pdf? My requirement is to append images to a single, searchable PDF, with each image being on a separate page (So, for 5 images taken, we need a PDF with 5 pages and these 5 pages should be searchable)

Comment: @JoiceGeorge Tesseract does not support reading PDF natively. You'd need to merge your images into a multi-page TIFF and feed that to the engine.